# How to return boolean value in lifecycleScope.launch

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

I have a corountine and I used lifecycleScope.launch and I want it to return a boolean value. How should I do that?

```
fun updateDb(restaurantEntity: RestaurantEntity, mode: Int): Boolean {
    val db =
        Room.databaseBuilder(requireContext(), RestaurantDatabase::class.java, "restaurant-db")
            .build()

    lifecycleScope.launch { 
        when (mode) {
            1 -> {
                val restaurant: RestaurantEntity =
                    db.restaurantDao().getAllRestaurant(restaurantEntity.restaurant_Id)
                db.close()
                return@async true
            }

            2 -> {
                db.restaurantDao().insertRestaurant(restaurantEntity)
                db.close()
                true
            }

            3 -> {
                db.restaurantDao().deleteRestaurant(restaurantEntity)
                db.close()
                true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

I used **return@async** true and used **return true** and just **true**, none of them works.

Comment: Can you please add more information? what is the layout? spinner and recyclerview are different things so how do you want to trigger both together. Need more information to understand the problem.

Comment: I have added few code lines @MohitAjwani

Comment: Hey @yazhini, please consider adding entier viewHolder and onBindViewHolder code and always try to give concise and all relevant information/code while asking the question. So community here can help you better.

Comment: I uploaded the entire code @ParagPawar

Comment: It's still incomplete, please post the entire adapter code with layout, we've no means to know what is the type for the list and how is the view hierarchy.

Comment: Can you please describe your problem with more information, more code and explanation.

Comment: I have a val finalprice in OrdeViewHolder(). This val calculates the price of the item when the quantiy changes. I want to use this val in OnBindView(). How o do that ? @hardartcore

Comment: What are you going to do with this variable in `onBindViewHolder` ? Can you give an example?

Comment: I want to add it to calculate the total amount,"total += data.itemPrice.toInt()" @hardartcore

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, but I once created a sample for a recyclerview that counted "checked" things and also faked a delay in the process displaying a progress bar. It's a bit old (a few months) so perhaps there's a few optimizations to make, but it should be quite simple to follow, as it consists of .. 5 small files at the most... [here it is in Github](https://github.com/Gryzor/CheckBoxCounter). I just updated the project to July 2021 dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you described in comments I think the best way to achieve this is to create a variable in your `OrderViewHolder` which will store the `finalPrice` so you can use it in your `Adapter`. Something similar to this:

```
class OrderViewHolder(
    itemView: View
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    // Init finalPrice
    var finalPrice: Int = 0

    override fun onItemSelected(
        parent: AdapterView<*>?,
        view: View?,
        position: Int,
        id: Long
    ) {

        // calculate finalPrice 
        finalPrice = (currentPrice * quantity!!).toString()
    }

}
```

And after that you can access `finalPrice` inside your adapter as:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(
    holder: OrderViewHolder, 
    position: Int
) {

    // Access finalPrice like ->
    holder.finalPrice

}
```

Comment: When I did this the value always remains 0 in onBindViewHolder()

Comment: Actually the final price is calculated for each dish, and after calculating it, the total amount is calculated like total += holder.finalPrice

Comment: The value is always 0 because probably you just copy pasted it directly without applying the calculation or initialization which you need to do to set the price.
So as far as I understand you have let's say adapter with 5 dishes which based on selected quantity it's price is changed and you have somewhere a total price which you show based on user's selection? Is that right?

Comment: Yes. That;s what I wanted to do

Comment: Damn, I see so many wrong things in that adapter...why are you adding everything inside your adapter's code? That's so wrong. I guess that button and the view you pass in the constructor are part of your Activity/Fragment's view not the ViewHolder itself. The adapter should not touch views which are not part of it's scope at all or even start activities.